# Importing a custom module

Tags: python, python-import

I am having a problem importing a script in another directory to the main script. FYI, this is a python Flask app. I have the empty `__init__.py` in the module_directory, so importing the module in the upper `__init__.py` should not be a problem, but it happens. I don't know why.

```
myfolder
    - __init__.py
    - module_directory
        - script_to_import.py
        - __init__.py
    - static
    - templates
```

`__init__.py` is the main server script where the app is defined with routes like `@app.route("/home", methods=["GET","POST"])` something like that. 
Below is what I do in the upper `__init__.py` to import the module.

```
from module_directory.script_to_import import *
```

It gives me error saying that `No module_directory`.

putting . in front of the module name fixed the problem.

```
from .module_directory.script_to_import import *
```

Comment: What executes the upper `__init__.py`?

Comment: @martineau it is the Flask app setting up url routes and running the actual app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 3):

I tried replicating it on my end

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── module_directory
    ├── __init__.py
    └── script_to_import.py
```

The `__init__.py` in `module_directory` is empty and `script_to_import.py` has:

```
def return_15():
    return 15
```

In the `__init__.py` of the `.` folder (which is nothing but `myfolder`), I have:

```
from module_directory.script_to_import import return_15

print(return_15())
```

When I run this file in the terminal, it gets executed and I get the following output

[image]